# Multi-threading for reactor consumers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I am using reactor to publish events throughout the application and have different consumers respond to their events.

Here is my reactor configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactor
public class ReactorConfiguration {

    static {
       Environment.initializeIfEmpty().assignErrorJournal();
    }

    @Bean
    public EventBus eventBus() {
       return EventBus.config().env(Environment.get()).dispatcher(Environment.SHARED).get();
}
```

I am expecting that the default ring buffer based dispatcher is used and multiple messages sent to a single consumer should be processed in parallel. Instead it seems to be processing events in a synchronous fashion. Thread `shared-1` is used to process my event1 to consumer1 and then only after completing the processing of event1, the same thread starts processing of event2 on consumer1.

How can I achieve parallel processing in a way that I should be able to send multiple events to multiple consumers and all events are processed in parallel.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

This is how I am dispatching events to the event bus

```
dispatch(ReactorEvents.REPORT_REQUEST_EVENT, "", event);

protected <T> void dispatch(String selector, String info, T event) {
    eventBus.notify(selector, Event.wrap(Tuple.of(info, event)));
}
```

and here is one of the consumers

```
@Consumer
public class ReportRequestHandler {
...
  @Selector(ReactorEvents.REPORT_REQUEST_EVENT)
  @Override
  public void handleRequest(Tuple2<String, ReportRequestEvent> tuple) {
    ReportRequestEvent event = tuple.getT2();
    log.debug("processing report request " + event.getId());
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like by simply changing to `dispatcher(Environment.WORK_QUEUE)` or `dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)` does what I want but I guess I need to understand the difference between the two a little more and secondly if the threadpool one will use the same threadpool as the rest of the application

Answer (score 1):

The default Ring Buffer implementation is single-threaded. That is why you are observing the side effects that you have described. For more detail about the various dispatcher choices available to you, please review the following link:

http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#_dispatchers